# How do I use zbot in Counter-Strike 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I'm quite an old fan of Counter-Strike. 3 or 4 years ago I was able to play Counter-Strike 1.6 with the Condition Zero bot (also called zbot). This bot is quite awesome as it it well programmed and automatically creates its waypoints.

I extracted everything as always in my cstrike directory, but apparently the bot doesn't load for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Play CZ instead maybe?

Comment: sorry, I rather play battlefield or minesweeper rather than cz

Answer (score 2):

The best option might be Condition Zero instead of plain CS 1.6

Z-Bot works still fine with the Steam Version:

- Download and extract the [ZBot ZIP-File](http://www.fileplanet.com/182178/180000/fileinfo/Counter-Strike-1.6---Z-Bot)
- Copy all files (*except* `liblist.gam` and `commandmenu.txt`) to your `...\Steam\SteamApps\\..\cstrike` directory
- In the Steam Game Library -> right click on Counter-Strike -> Properties -> Launch Options and add `-dll "dlls\zbotcz"`
- Now you can run the game

Answer (score 0):

I don't think zbot works with Steam. It was designed to work with non-Steam CS 1.6 which is also outdated by now.

Comment: zbot was developed by turtle studios to provide bots to cs:cz, but it also worked for cs 1.6.

Comment: It's the same engine on both so basically you can say it either way. But I was emphasizing the "non-Steam" part anyway. ;) The point is - zbot is pretty outdated so it won't work with updated CS:CZ/CS1.6. It will only work with old versions it was designed for, if you can find them.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add bots using following steps:

1. Download zBots from here -->  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_mNu5ekLshNS0dlX3ltcFVIYUU/edit?usp=sharing
2. After downloading Extract the files.
3. Now copy these files into your cstrike directory.
     For STEAM: C:/ProgramFiles/Steam/Steamapps/common/HalfLife/cstrike
     For Non STEAM: C:/ProgramFiles/Valve/Counter-strike/cstrike
4. It will ask for Replace Files, replace them and you are done.

Now open the game and use simple commands like "bot_add_ct" etc.

Source --> http://www.nkscslovers.co.in/2014/09/how-to-add-bots-in-counter-strike-16.html