# How to add bots in Counter Strike 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I have followed the instructions by [fileplanet](http://www.fileplanet.com/182178/180000/fileinfo/Counter-Strike-1.6---Z-Bot):

> Instllation: 
>   1. Download: ZBot - CS Bots
>
> Before You start installing Zbot it might be a good idea to backup
>   your current settings just in case. Either backup your entire cstrike
>   folder or just the file "liblist.gam" (this is where the changes are
>   made).
>
> 2. Unzip
>
> Unzip the entire content of the zip to your Counter-Strike folder.
>   Should look something like this:

But I'm confused about the below line -  what does it mean?

> Kod:
>   /SteamApps/mail@mail.com/Counter-Strike/

I press "**H**" to add bots in game, but the console says

**`unknown command bot_add_ct`**

I also checked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16456/how-do-i-use-zbot-in-counter-strike-1-6):

> In the Steam Game --> right click on Counter-Strike -> Properties -> Launch Options and add -dll "dlls\zbotcz"

But I cannot understand how to do that.